# how to resovle confusing pip and pip3 in ubuntu?

Tags: python3, pip, python-2.7

Using Ubuntu 20.04, I checked my python and pip version which are:

```
python -V:
Python 2.7.18

python3 -V:
Python 3.8.5

which python
/usr/bin/python
    
which python3
/usr/bin/python3
    
pip -V
pip 21.0.1 from /home/mas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

pip3 -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Why I see two pip in two different location of python3? Shouldn't **pip -V** refers to python2 pip?

The last command I ran was:

`/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Check your output: Your `pip` is in `/home/mas/.local/`, which means that it's not from the Ubuntu repositories. When you install random non-Ubuntu software, you get what you get.

Comment: @user535733 how to remove it?

Comment: Edit your question. Currently your question is "*Shouldn't pip -V refers to python2 pip?*"

Comment: @user535733 the command upgraded the pip3 in /usr/bin. My concern is with pip 21.0.1

Comment: How you remove software depends upon how you installed it. Tell us how you installed 21.0.1, and we'll tell you the right way to uninstall it.

Comment: @user535733 used `sudo apt-get purge python-pip` and removed 20.0.2. My problem is: where is the python2 pip? now both pip -V and pip3 -V refers to pip 21 in python3.8

Comment: We did not cause that name conflict. You installed some non-Ubuntu software with a seemingly non-standard name. Since Python2 is deprecated, you should be weaning yourself off pip2 anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296009/how-to-uninstall-duplicate-pip-in-python3-on-ubuntu-20-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296009/how-to-uninstall-duplicate-pip-in-python3-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: My output matches yours except I don't have a pip command.  I think that Ubuntu relies on python (python 2.7.18) for system maintenance, and they're trying to get out of that.  If you're interested in doing software development with python, I strongly recommend anaconda  ( https://anaconda.org/ ) to maintain separate environments if you need different versions of python to build things.  Another good thing is that Anaconda's environments, and GUIs such as anaconda navigator work the same in other non-Ubuntu environments such as MacOS and Windows.